# Models y Forms en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo una pregunta que siempre me estanca en todos los proyectos que empiezo. No se exactamente cuando poner ciertos datos en el models y otros en el forms.

Las preguntas serian:

¿Para que sirve el models? ¿Y para que sirve el forms? ¿Que datos van en el primero, y cuales en el segundo?

Lo que tenia entendido es que los models, los datos se guardan en la base de datos, mientras que los forms aparecen en el django admin.

Saludos a toda la comunidad!

Comment: Te sugerimos revisar [ask],saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los `Model`s permiten definir de una manera fácil y rápida las tablas de una base de datos. También proporcionan una API sencilla para obtener y crear datos a partir de esas tablas.

Los `ModelForm`s proporcionan una interfaz para la creación de formularios para la web (en HTML), a partir de los campos que has definido anteriormente en el modelo de datos. Esto evita duplicar el código necesario, ya los campos ya han sido definidos para la base de datos.

Por ejemplo, tenemos el siguiente modelo de datos para un autor:

```py
TITLE_CHOICES = [
    ('MR', 'Mr.'),
    ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
    ('MS', 'Ms.'),
]

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Ahora podríamos crear un `ModelForm` a partir del modelo para crear posteriormente un formulario:

```py
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'birth_date']
```

Finalmente ya puedes gestionar los formularios en tu vista, por ejemplo:

```py
form = ArticleForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

El objeto `form` puede ser pasado a la plantilla y crea un formulario HTML automáticamente:

```
{{ form }}
```

Para más información puedes consultar [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: Esto ya me aclaro casi todo, pero me sigue faltando algo. Los forms, no los modelsforms.

Comment: @LucasLeone funcionan casi igual, la única diferencia es que los `Forms` no gestionan un modelo, es decir su papel principal es limpiar y validar los datos y a su ves normalizarlos a objeto Python, ademas de generar el código HTML automáticamente, que también es una funcionalidad bastante importante. Esta respuesta esta exquisita XDD

Answer (score 2):

**¿Para que sirve el models?**

El archivo models.py tiene como función operar como si fuese una base de datos usando la metodología POO *acrónimo de Programación Orientada a Objetos* (si no configuraste el archivo Settings.py por defecto éste usará SQLite)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

**¿Que datos van en el primero, y cuales en el segundo?**

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta, los datos que se utilizan frecuentemente en la primera pregunta models.py son Clases, Métodos y Atributos.

Un ejemplo simple sería:

```
Class NombreTabla(models.Model):
   nombre=models.CharField(max_length=20)
   Fecha=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

esta es una simple ayuda/guía de mi parte, quizá no ayude mucho pero almenos te daría una idea de como sería su uso... tu pregunta es muy concisa deberías buscar en la documentación de Django, te la recomiendo esta muy completa y bien hecha.

Comment: Me sirve esta respuesta, pero ando buscando algo mucho mas completo, aunque me orientaste un poco!